# Wanna run Pyspark from Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

My problem statement is I have pyspark mllib code and I want to run this from hazelcast means connect Spark from hazelcast and run my pyspark code do not want to connect hazelcast from Spark and run the code I have also gone through hazelcast-spark connector but its a one way. 
Is there any resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that complex stuff? Just try Hazelcast Jet:
https://jet.hazelcast.org/

It's natively integrated.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes its right we can use hazelcast jet but does jet support python means can I write code in python and call pyspark mllib?